# How to split the string which are in this desired format?

Tags: java, string, split

I have the below text format

```
 String s = "
 key1:value1;
 key2:value2;
 key3:value3;
 key4:value4;
 key5:value5;
 key6:https://url1.com, https://url2.com;
 key7:value;";
 Note: (the number of urls in key6 will be 1 to many and non linear)
```

I am splitting the s with 7 key-value chunks using S.split(";")

```
 String keyValPair[] =  s.split(";");
  Output will be
  /* keyValPair[0] contains key1:value
     keyValPair[1] contains key2:value
     keyValPair[2] contains key3:value and 
     keyValPair[6] contains key6:https://url1.com,https://url2.com;
```

Now I want to again split key and value separately and store it in arrays 0 and ist position.

```
     //while looping into keyValPair[i]
     String[] singleKeyVal[] = keyValPair[0].split(":");
     /*Output
         singleKeyVal[0] will have Key1
         singleKeyVal[1] will have Value1
          perform some task and clear the array singlekeyVal[]
```

The question is how to correctly split the Key6

```
 //while looping into KeyValPair[i]
 String[] singleKeyVal[] = keyValPair[5].split(":");  //6th chunk contains : in the URL too
 /*Output
     singleKeyVal[0] will have Key6
     singleKeyVal[1] should contain https://url1.com,https://url2.com
     also note that above example contains only 2 urls but it will contain urls between 1 to many urls,
```

Comment: Instead of splitting use indexOf(":") and use the substring from the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two `split` methods - [the second one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)  takes a `limit` argument that allows you to specify the maximum number of groups you want. In your case:

```
String[] singleKeyVal = keyValPair[5].split(":", 2);
```

should do what you want.

ps: you should adopt Java naming conventions (variables start in lower case).

Answer (score 3):

There is [an overloaded `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) that takes a second argument called `limit`:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

So use

```
String[] SingleKeyVal[] = KeyValPair[5].split(":", 2);
```

to only split once and get an array with size 2.